# url format to redirect to a particular page after login in .net web apps?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http

What is the url format to redirect to a particular page after the user logs into a .NET web app? I need to write a custom session management js module which redirects users to the login page automatically after a given period of time.

I need to create the url so the system will redirect the user back to the page that the user was on when the timeout occurred automatically after login. What is the correct url format for this?  I think I've seen .NET append this redirect url as part of its native process but I'm having problems recreating that scenario right now.

I know the following format isn't correct but the redirect url that .NET uses looks something along these lines:

http://localhost:63419/Login.aspx?Redirect=http://localhost:63419/AccountManagement

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:63419/Login.aspx?Redirect=/AccountManagement

Comment: The redirect URLs are most of the time relative to the website unless required to be Absolute